# My Program stops after 2nd intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

My android application stops after **startActivity ()** call of my 2nd intent. It works perfectly for the first time with intents. But on the 2nd time its control doesn't pass to 3rd activity. I haven't displayed anything on 2nd activity. Is it the problem? Or is something with my `AndroidManifest.xml` file?
Can some one help me?
I have added the intent filter of three activities as shown below.Is it the problem? I am new to android so please help me!

```
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Can you give your code how do you start new Activity? What do you mean in _application stops after startActivity ()_?If it crashes then provide your log

Comment: @Ilya Blokh it doesn't crash instead the control remains the line after startActivity() prompting for something

Comment: my stack has the following 
**Thread [<3> main] (Running) 
Thread [<13> Binder Thread #2] (Running) 
Thread [<11> Binder Thread #1] (Running)**

Comment: Your Logcat and source code needed to understand the source of problem

Comment: @ Ilya Blokh My code need to start an intent which pass control to a class called SendMsg I have added the below code for that
 _Intent i=new Intent(AfterLogin.this,SendMsg.class); Bundle b=new Bundle(); b.putString("message", msg); i.putExtras(b); startActivity(i);_

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you edit it considering all comments that have been added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any activity that isn't the main one use the following:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Only the original activity should have the following:

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Comment: @ Samir 
My code need to start an intent which pass control to a class called **SendMsg** I have added the below code for that
_Intent i=new Intent(AfterLogin.this,SendMsg.class);
         Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putString("message", msg);
            i.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(i);_

Comment: SendMsg class declare in Manifiest file and check there <category />

Comment: this the manifest part of the  destination class of intent
**<activity android:name=".SendMsg">
         <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        
        </activity>**

Comment: CTRL + click on ".SendMsg",whats happen?

Comment: you meant ctrl+ click on .SendMsg on AndroidManifest.xml?It resulted  showing lik this
**manifest/application/activity**

Comment: It resulted showing lik this **manifest/application/activity**
I am new to android.

Comment: its have to open your SendMsg class

Comment: ya i know that it works in eclipse i mean when you click with CTRL its open your SendMsg class If not it your Bug and cant call activity proper and Give path with package like com.your.yourproject.sendmsg...

Comment: path with package means?Did you mean the path of SendMsg in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: after this You cant tick my answer ?

Comment: i just voted the answer .voting means  sending feed back right?